# conditional statement not working Java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
int number;
  int randomNum1= (int)(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
 int randomNum2= (int)(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
    try{
        number = Integer.parseInt(this.txtInput.getText());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please input a integer.", "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
        }                
    if (number > randomNum1 && number < randomNum2 ||  number > randomNum2 && number  < randomNum1){
    lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));
    lblRand2.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum2));
    lblOutput.setText("YOU WIN.");
    }else
    lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));
    lblRand2.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum2));
    lblOutput.setText("YOU LOSE.");
```

why does it always display you lose even my input is a number that must win?

Comment: whats the condition to contribute a win?

Comment: It's Java and **not** JAVA.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot `{}` for `else` thats why `Lose` statement is always executed.

- Thats why the only statement in `else` block is
  `lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));`
- After that, program will flow normally to execute `lblOutput.setText("YOU LOSE.");`
- Hence, even if your `if` condition is `true` and label is set with `You Win`, `lblOutput.setTest("You Lost")` is executed as result of normal program execution as it is not in `else` block

Change

```
else
lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));
lblRand2.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum2));
lblOutput.setText("YOU LOSE.");
```

to

```
else{

lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));
    lblRand2.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum2));
    lblOutput.setText("YOU LOSE.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Never** use statements without curly braces (see your `else`!)

```
if ([...]){
  ...
}else
lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));
lblRand2.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum2));
lblOutput.setText("YOU LOSE.");
```

is equivalent to

```
if ([...]){
  ...
} else {
  lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));
}
lblRand2.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum2));
lblOutput.setText("YOU LOSE.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the block for the else.

Besides you can use `Math.max` and `Math.min` to simplify your condition

```
lblRand1.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum1));
lblRand2.setText(Integer.toString(randomNum2));
if (number > Math.min(randomNum1, randomNum2) 
    && number < Math.max(randomNum1, randomNum2)){
    lblOutput.setText("YOU WIN.");
} else {
    lblOutput.setText("YOU LOSE.");
}
```